# When should I use a semicolon after curly braces?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Many times I've seen a semicolon used after a function declaration, or after the anonymous "return" function of a Module Pattern script. When is it appropriate to use a semicolon after curly braces?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You use a semicolon after a statement. This is a statement:

```js
var foo = function() {
  alert("bar");
};
```

because it is a variable assignment (i.e. creating and assigning an anonymous function to a variable).

The two things that spring to mind that aren't statements are function declarations:

```js
function foo() {
  alert("bar");
}
```

and blocks:

```js
{
  alert("foo");
}
```

**Note:** that same block construct without semi-colon also applies to `for`, `do` and `while` loops.

Comment: Also after var foo = {"prop1":1,"prop2":2}; etc.

Comment: @Robusto that's a variable assignment.

Comment: @cletus: It still needs a semicolon.

Comment: @SLaks I know, it needs a semi-colon because it's a variable assignment (that was my point).

Comment: @Cletus: Just wanted to extend what you said, so OP didn't think you only meant function literals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for. I often lose track of the smaller (albeit important) details when attempting to wrap my head around some of the more advanced concepts.

Comment: This also applies to `if` statements.

Answer (score 25):

It matters too when you intend to minify your code.

So I personally add one after every `}` where [automatic semicolon insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) (ASI) would insert one.

I wrote a post about [ASI in JavaScript](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-semicolons).

Comment: @alegz Works for me

Answer (score 20):

### Don't use a semicolon:

...if it's just your every-day function declaration:

```
function foo() {

} // No semicolon
```

### Use a semicolon:

...if it's an assignment:

```
var foo = function() {

}; // Semicolon
```

...or a self invoking function:

```
(function () {

})(); // Semicolon
```

Answer (score 10):

You never need to; you always can (except before `else` and `while`).

### Explanation:

Unfortunately, JavaScript semicolons are optional. 
Therefore, you never need to add a semicolon.

It is (very) good practice to terminate every *statement* with a semicolon. 
The only statements that end with a `}` are statements ending with an object literal (e.g. JSON) or function expression.

Therefore, best practice is to put semicolons after the following two braces (only):

```
var myFunc = function() { };
var myobject = { };
```

Comment: Is using `function someFunc(){ };` is still a statement that needs semicolon?

Comment: You "need" to if you want your minified Javascript to work in IE, which is the only browser I've found that chokes without them. Firefox/Chrome/Safari don't care about semicolons after statements.

Comment: @Cerin: I don't think that's true.

Comment: @SLaks, Try it yourself. Minify JS without semicolons and try running it in IE9. I just wasted several hours of my life figuring this out. Thought I'd share to others the hassle.

Comment: @Cerin: I tried it worked in IE9. Could you share the minified sample you are using to test?

Answer (score 5):

If we have a self-invoking function, we need to put a semicolon before it, otherwise it becomes part of the previous assignment statement. Consider the following:

```
testClass = function(name) {
  document.write ("Instantiating testClass<br />");
  this.name = name;
}

testClass.prototype.report = function() {
  document.write ("I'm " + this.name + "<br />");
  return 1;
}

testClass.prototype.testMethod = function(param) {
  document.write ("Running testMethod with parameter value " + param + "<br />");
  return 2;
} // notice that there is no semicolon here

(function() {
  document.write ("Running self-invoking function<br />");
  return 3;
}());

if (typeof(testClass.prototype.testMethod) !== "function") {
  document.write ("testMethod type: " + typeof(testClass.prototype.testMethod));
  document.write (", value: " + testClass.prototype.testMethod + "<br />");
}
var testOb = new testClass("Bill");
testOb.report();
testOb.testMethod(4);
```

This will produce the following output:

> "Running self-invoking function
>  Running testMethod with
>   parameter value 3
>  testMethod type: number, value: 2
>   Instantiating testClass
>  I'm Bill"

...plus a JavaScript error reported by the browser: `testOb.testMethod is not a function`
This is certainly not what we intended. Why is `testMethod` running immediately, before we have even instantiated the class? And why does it no longer exist when we want to call it as a member method?

What is happening is that `testMethod` is being assigned not our function definition, but the return value of the function definition. And the function definition itself is being run anonymously. This is how:

1. The `testClass` constructor and the member method `report` are successfully defined/assigned.
2. Because of the lack of a semicolon after the definition for `testMethod`, the `()` surrounding the following self-invoking function becomes an invocation operator, which causes **what we think is our definition of** `testMethod` to become an anonymous function that is invoked immediately, and the return value of the following anonymous function becomes its parameter list. This explains the order of printed output - our self-invoking function is run first as it is evaluated as a parameter.
3. Since our intended function definition returns 2, it is this 2 that is assigned to `testMethod`, and **not** the function definition. This is confirmed by our printing of the type and value of `testMethod`.
4. Now `testClass` is successfully instantiated as `testOb` and its `report` method works as intended, proving that the class definition is otherwise intact.
5. When we try to call `testMethod`, we are told by the interpreter that it is not a function - and rightly so, because it is a number with the value 2.

If we put a semicolon after the definition of `testMethod`, it will separate its assignment from the calling of the self-invoking function, and we will have the result we expected:

> "Running self-invoking function
>  Instantiating testClass
>   I'm Bill
>  Running testMethod with parameter value 4"

Or we could even put it directly before the anonymous function:

```
;(function() {...
```

But I suggest that since the problem is due to the lack of a semicolon at the end of an assignment statement, we should perhaps make a habit of always putting a semicolon after defining functions in this way. i.e. all of my functions above should have a semicolon after the closing brace, because they are all assignments of anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3):

You also should use a semicolon after a curly bracket after returning a function within a function in JavaScript.

```
function watchOut(problem) {
  return function(number, location) {
    alert("Be careful! There are " + problem +
          " today!\n" +

          number + " have been spotted at the " + location + "!"
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
// This will break code

a=b=c=d=e=1
a = b + c     // Semicolon required here
(d + e).toString()
```

It will return "Property of object [object Object] is not a function". Because it will actually be executed as:

```
a = b + c(d + e).toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

Semicolons go at the end of lines that do not end in a curly brace or to separate statements  on the same line. It does no harm to use them after a closing brace, or to wear suspenders and a belt, but it does look a little nerdy.