# Why are semicolons not used after if/else statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I understand that it is good syntax to use semicolons after all statements in Javascript, but does any one know why if/else statements do not require them after the curly braces?

Comment: `while { } do` and `for () { }` have this property too.

Comment: This is about the language grammar. You know what that is, look for "Statements" [here](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/grammar14.html).

Comment: [When should I use a semicolon after curly braces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces)

Comment: This is a question about grammar of a language; I do not see why this should have been closed as non-constructive.

Comment: Readers: if you think this should not have been closed, then click re-open.

Comment: Readers:  Wow, that worked :-} Question is no longer closed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

- Semicolon is used to end ONE statement
- `{` and `}` begin and close a group of statements

Basically, an `if-else` must be followed by either a statement or a group of statements.

`if-else` followed by a statement:

```
if (condition) statement;
if (condition); // followed by a statement (an empty statement)
```

`if-else` followed by group of statements:

```
if (condition) {
   statement;
   statement;
}

if (condition) {
   // followed by a group of statements of zero length
}
```

`if-else` must end with a `;` if it is followed by a single statement. `if-else` does not end with a `;` when followed by a group of statements because `;` is used to end a single statement, and is not used for ending a group of statements.

Comment: I disagree with "even if-else must end with ;". Any statement in javascript need not end with ; FYI. There is no strict rule as such.

Comment: Any statement that is not contextualy terminated (ie by curly braces) needs a ;

Comment: @Orangepill JavaScript doesn't have that strict rule, but it's recommended anyway.

Comment: @Jack Right, you'll need semicolon in that case. Didn't think about coding in that fashion

Comment: @jack Are you referring to Javascript's semicolon insertion rules? Note the term is semicolon insertion, even if you don't put them there the parser does.

Comment: @Orangepill That technical detail doesn't matter to the argument though.

Comment: @jack True.. the discussion is centered around language syntax and semicolon insertion is a language "feature".

Comment: I did not aware of "Semicolon Insertion" (didn't even know it exists), but I found it is a little silly for us to remember extra rules just to omit one semi-colon once every five to ten lines. Or maybe there is advantage of using it that I am not aware of.

Comment: @invisal I whole heartedly agree. I think it was put there as a means to be forgiving to non-programmers early on but instead it tends to just mask bugs by making programs run that would otherwise error out.

Comment: @invisal Yes. That is exactly why I asked. I'm new to javascript and I found it very odd that certain statements required semicolons whereas some did not. I just automatically adds semicolons after every curly brace for consistency in my code.

Comment: Where are the `else`'s in the code examples?

Answer (score 14):

The real answer is because many modern languages copied their syntax from C, which has this property.  JavaScript is one of these languages.

C allows statement blocks

```
 { ... }
```

(which don't need terminating semicolons) to be used where statements can be used. So you can use statement blocks as then- and else- clauses, without the semicolons.

If you place a *single* statement in the then- or else- clause, you'll need to terminate it with a semicolon.  Again, just as in C, with the extra JavaScript twist that ; is optional at the end of a line, if inserting it would not cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 8):

Because the curly braces themselves are termination characters.

They are tokens that enclose a compound statement block and are intrinsically terminated. It's like putting a period at the end of a sentence, it signals to the parser that the thought is complete.

While being completely ugly it is valid to wrap every statement in {} and omit the ;

Comment: But you can omit the ; by wrapping in {}

Comment: Definitely does not pass js lint