# Else if and Else in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I wrote a small javascript code, but it has a problem, the page can not show anything. I think the problem is in the line "else if..." or "else...", because if I comment these two lines, the code runs without any problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        var var1 = window.prompt("please input");
        var var2 = window.prompt("please input2");
        var1 = parseFloat(var1);
        var2 = parseFloat(var2);

        if (var1< var2) {document.writeln("the second number is bigger")};
        else if (var1> var2) {document.writeln("the first number is bigger")};
        else {document.writeln("They are the same")};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the `;` from the closing braces of your if statements.

Comment: Take a look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/www139/c0fj5bmg/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Merry Christmas and hope you are successful at learning JavaScript.

Comment: Also, Always check the console http://i.imgur.com/nv2MHFp.png

Comment: @www139 Thanks! i am so careless. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon, `;`, from after the brackets of your `if statements`:

```
    if (var1< var2) {document.writeln("the second number is bigger")}
    else if (var1> var2) {document.writeln("the first number is bigger")}
    else {document.writeln("They are the same")}
```

Have a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17036218/4206206

Essestially, a semicolon isn't used to end a group of statements, but rather to end a **single** statement.

---

*A point with your code, if you're using HTML5 you don't need the `language="javascript"` in your script tags:*

```
<script language="javascript">
```

*Can become simply*

```
<script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript should be like this

```js
var var1 = window.prompt("please input");
var var2 = window.prompt("please input2");
var1 = parseFloat(var1);
var2 = parseFloat(var2);

if (var1 < var2) {
  document.writeln("the second number is bigger");
} else if (var1 > var2) {
  document.writeln("the first number is bigger");
} else {
  document.writeln("They are the same");
}
```

Comment: I beat you to an answer earlier today, also, Praveen ;D

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Merry Christmas! LoL.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        var var1 = window.prompt("please input");
        var var2 = window.prompt("please input2");
        var1 = parseFloat(var1);
        var2 = parseFloat(var2);

        if (var1 < var2) {
            document.writeln("the second number is bigger");
        }
        else if (var1 > var2) {
            document.writeln("the first number is bigger");
        }
        else {
            document.writeln("They are the same");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

your semi colons were wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
if (var1< var2) {document.writeln(" ... ")};
                                           ^
```

Your `semicolons` at the end of your if, else if, and else blocks are your issue. They are prematurely ending your if blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure you `parseFloat` before you compare, because it just compares as string, and remember, 10 comes before 2, so by string `10 < 2`! And you don't need the `;` at the end:

```
var var1 = window.prompt("please input");
var var2 = window.prompt("please input2");
var1 = parseFloat(var1);
var2 = parseFloat(var2);

if (var1 < var2) {
  document.writeln("the second number is bigger");
} else if (var1 > var2) {
  document.writeln("the first number is bigger");
} else {
  document.writeln("They are the same");
}
```