# Javascript variable is null but goes in if-statement

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of a weird problem. I TRIED to create a jsfiddle but I don't get the same result so I'm sorry I can't share more of what I have.

```
var parent = id && Number(oldParent) !== 1 ? $('#main_container #item_' + itemId).parent().parent().prev() : null;
```

This is how I get the parent. It should be null when it isn't needed.

Later, I get this check in the same function:

```
if (parent && parent != null && !parent.hasClass('.main-group'));
{
    console.log(parent == null);
    var siblingCount = parent.next().children().length;

    if (siblingCount === 0)
    {
        parent.removeClass('group');
        parent.addClass('normal-item');
    }
}
```

So, I check if parent is set (just in case), parent is not null and parent doesn't have the class `main-group`. This should work, at least I thought, but I get the error:

`TypeError: parent is null`

On this row:

`var siblingCount = parent.next().children().length;`

So, that's why I added the console log to see if parent is null. Guess what? The console.log says true. This means parent is equal to null, but it still goes IN the if-statement. I use && so it shouldn't go in the if statement because already one operation is false.

I had others look at it and they couldn't figure it out either.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon at the end of `if` statement

Comment: Apart from the semicolon at the end, there is no need for the `!=null` check as your initially checking if parent is truthy `if(parent)` a truthy value can't be null.

Comment: Yes I know but it didn't work so I tried a sh*tload of stuff, I was even checking on null as string since I didn't know anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `semicolan` at the end which is making it to execute as the `statement` is terminated and next statement `executes`.

```
var parent = null;
if (parent && parent != null && !parent.hasClass('.main-group'));{
   alert("Hello");
}
```

For Debin comment:

```
var parent = null;
if (parent != null); { alert("Vinoth") }

// The above one is equivalent:

if (parent != null) do nothing ;
alert ("hi");
```

JavaScript thinks that you have an `empty` statement and everything to right of it is treated as no longer belonging to the if condition and thus an `independent` one making it to `execute`.

Comment: How `;` be there after if ?

Comment: Well I'm stupid I guess, don't know why I had a semicolon at the end of the if. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. Didn't see it actually.

Comment: if you do `if (condition);` then it will be an empty statement

Comment: well thnx to welcome me btw read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036135/why-is-it-that-semicolons-are-not-used-after-if-else-statements..if I am wrong then let meknow..if(); then next statement will be definatly executed..it won't depend on condition which may b OP doesnot want :)

Comment: @debin: i am not able to edit my post for some reason, i will update your thought... once its... there

Comment: @debin: please do look at my answer, which is what you are also thinking

Comment: @debin: That was my first statement "Welcome to JavaScript"!!!, i guess i missed to add "Weird world" there...

Answer (score 1):

You have a ";" at the end of this line

```
if (parent && parent != null && !parent.hasClass('.main-group'));
```

This is what is causing the problem.