# Issue forEach JS array

Tags: javascript, foreach

Here is my code JS :

```
var items = [255, 255, 255, 255];
items.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item = 255) {
        item = 0;
    };
});
console.log(items)
```

In console.log I get `[255, 255, 255, 255]`, why it doesn't change to `[0, 0, 0, 0]`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using an assignment operator "=" instead of "==" or "===".

Comment: looks like an assignment issue

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.map`.

`.forEach` doesn't return anything, it is used to run a function with each item. `.map` returns a value for each iteration it runs.

```
var items = [255, 255, 255, 255]
items = items.map(item => item === 255 ? 0 : item)

console.log(items) // [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are just changing the value type argument, nothing will happen with the items in the array. You can just change it to use `map` instead and create a new array

```
items = items.map( item => item === 255 ? 0 : item );
```

As remarked in the comments, in the original code, you also used an assignment operator instead of a compare operator

When you do:

```
if (item = 255)
```

You will assign item with 255 (which will be truthy, and then go into the if statement where you are assigning it with `0`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains two bugs.

1. `=` is assignment, not comparison. Your function is equivalent to:

   ```
   function (item) {
       item = 255;
       item = 0;
   }
   ```
2. `item` is a function parameter, i.e. a local variable in the anonymous function. Assigning to `item` has no effect on the `items` array:

   ```
   var x = 255;
   (function (y) { y = 0; })(x);
   console.log(x);
   // 255
   ```

Comment: Good question, all that replied got an instant downvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could take the reference to the array for changing the value inside of the callback for [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

BTW, after a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), there is [no need for a semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036135/why-are-semicolons-not-used-after-if-else-statements).

```js
var items = [255, 255, 255, 255];

items.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
//                                  ^^^^^
    if (item = 255) {
        array[index] = 0;
    }
//   ^ no semicolon needed
});

console.log(items);
```