# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function on "(function($)"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get the following error...

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

...at the following line, of a certain JS script?

`(function($){`

And why do I get that error only when JS are concatenated? (I'm using Gulp)

And why does it work if I add `;` before that line, like that:

`;(function($){`

?

**update**

The preceding line - that is, the object which is not a function, according to the runtime error - on the concatened script was a `}`, as in:

```
storage = {
   //...
}
```

I'm used to always put semicolon, but not after curly braces.

Turns out the curly braces could delimit the end of a statement, like in this case, and then  it's recommended to use the semicolon to avoid this error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces)'s a good explanation.

Comment: please provide a full example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145514/whats-the-purpose-of-starting-semi-colon-at-beginning-of-javascript

Comment: Have a look at the previous line and you'll see the object that is not a function. Put a semicolon *there* (not in front of the IIFE)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do)

Comment: @eithedog Or the question it's a dupe of; when questions are dupes, vote to close.

Comment: @Bergi it is a bad practice to put semicolon before the IIFE too, just in case?

Comment: @zok: Not really, but it *should* be an unnecessary practise :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript ignore missing semi-colon and try to interpret it. So if you don't input the semi-colon, it use the next line to see if it should end the line or chain it.

That allow you to use thing like this :

```
String
.split();
```

and it will be interpreted like that :

```
String.split();
```

**But**, this would also work :

```
String
.split
();
```

Now, If you have something like this :

```
var a = 'a';
var b = a
(function(){})
```

JavaScript has no way to know what you really want to do, so it will interpret it like that :

```
var a = 'a';
var b = a(function(){});
```

Giving you the error `[place object type here] is not a function`

**Bottom line, always put your semi-colon.**

---

## Edit

After seeing your code, here how it is interpreted :

```
storage = {/**/}(function($){})(jQuery);
```

So `Object` (`{} === Object`) is not a `function`

Answer (score 1):

When concatenated it believes you're trying to call whatever precedes the `(function($) {...}`.

If you put `()` after a reference it tries to call whatever the reference is. This is why you'll see a lot of JavaScript libraries precede their code with a lone `;`