# jQuery UI Autocomplete with urls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I try to get an instant search with jquery ui autocomplete, I want to add link onclick result.

**JScript**

```
$("#searchinput").autocomplete({
    source: "search/get_searchdata",
    select:function(e,ui) { 
        location.href = ui.item.the_link;
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="searchinput">
</div>
```

The script work and show me results from array:

**Array**

```
[
    {
        "label": "Apple annuncia OS X El Capitan",
        "the_link": "../../../post/2"
    },
    {
        "label": "Apple l'Phone flessibile",
        "the_link": "../../../post/5325"
    },
    {
        "label": "iCloud Apple, attacco hacker in Cina",
        "the_link": "../../../post/5637"
    }
]
/* Lint by jsonlint.com */
```

But when i click a result the page not change.

Note: I use jQuery 1.9.1 version.

Comment: What does the alert function in your code do?

Comment: Sorry mistake, removed but still not working.
ps. Alert do not shot anything.

Comment: You still have a semicolon that's a syntax error ?

Comment: After the `select` property

Comment: And I've tested it, and it works just fine for me

Comment: Sorry i not understand, I upload the current code.

Comment: @adeneo It work and shot me result but links do no work

Comment: Here's a working example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1udLh2cs/2/**

Comment: Thanks I think the problem is not in this source, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you looking for?

[Code working](http://jsfiddle.net/alysonsm/d8zsh39L/1/)
Html
`<div class="ui-widget">
<input id="searchinput"/>
</div>`

JavaScript

```
var jsonData = [ {
    "label": "Apple annuncia OS X El Capitan",
    "the_link": "http://www.apple.com"
},{
    "label": "Apple l'Phone flessibile",
    "the_link": "http://www.apple.com/iphone"
},{
    "label": "iCloud Apple, attacco hacker in Cina",
    "the_link": "http://www.icloud.com"
}];

$("#searchinput").autocomplete({
source: jsonData,
select: function(event,ui) { 
    window.location.href = ui.item.the_link;
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks but i already solved the problem, the problem is Netbeans that not sync my copy with server .

Answer (score 2):

It is a syntax error, when objects are assigned, they should not have [semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces):

```
$("#searchinput").autocomplete({
    source: "search/get_searchdata",
    select:function(e,ui) { 
        location.href = ui.item.the_link;
    }; //<-- remove ; incorrect semicolon
}); //<- correct usage
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, Netbeans not sync version of my PC with the server.

Thanks anyway to all answers.